# How to pass a variable in the workspace to update() in R

Tags: r

as the title says, I don't know how to pass a variable, which is a predictor, to the function `update()` in R. Below you can find a minimum example to work on. I want to eliminate the variable `cyl` because it is not significant. As you can see, if I pass as a pure name like we do in a `lm()` call, everything works. But if I need to store, for whatever reason, the name somewhere and then pass it to `update()` then the function simply ignores it.

model1 is the complete model:

```
model1 = lm( hp ~ qsec + cyl + mpg, data = mtcars )
summary( model1 )
```

model2 is the working reduced model

```
model2 = update( model1, . ~ . - cyl )
summary( model2 )
```

model2_notworking is the not working reduced model

```
var_to_delete = "cyl"
model2_notworking = update( model1, . ~ . - var_to_delete )
summary( model2_notworking )
```

I think the problem is in the way I store the name. I tried out with different combination of `eval()`, `noquote()`, `name()` and so on so forth but nothing seems to work.

Comment: your code works fine for me. What do you mean by "model2_notworking is the not working reduced model"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code does it produces a formula `hp ~ qsec + cyl + mpg - var_to_delete`. Instead you should update the formula by passing the variable name, e.g. like this

```
fit <- lm(hp ~ qsec + cyl + mpg, data = mtcars)

update(fit, . ~ . - mpg )

var_to_delete <- "mpg"
update(fit, as.formula(paste0(". ~ . - ", var_to_delete)) )
```